# How to use form.getvalues() to return only form fields - ExtJS

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a form that has several fields and a grid that contains some editors (i.e. textfield). 
I have noticed that form.getvalues() returns form fields as it should, but it also returns grid's editor fields. How can I avoid that? I only need form fields.

From debugger

```
     form.getValues() : Object
           contact.address : "some address",
           contact.city    : "London",
           photo.profile   : "photo1.jpg" //this is a field in grid editor
```

For the moment I avoid this from happening manually. It would be nice if there a default approach.

For grids I have tried

```
          getStore().removeAll()
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Does your grid really need to be a child of your form component?

Comment: That's a good point to rethink, but maybe YES. The main form has as childs other forms and grids. So I just need one function to collect all information for the childs. `form.getValues()` should return from all forms as it does. I am thinking that maybe a solution would be to find all subforms of the main form and then do `getValues()` at subforms. In this case I can avoid form-grid child relation

Answer (score 1):

Ext 4.2.2 already contains the fix of this problem so upgrade if you can. If you cannot, try to configure your grid editors with `isFormField:false` flag.

Comment: I think I currently use 4.2.0. I'll check the version. In any case `isFormField:false` should do the job

Comment: Confirm please when you test it. I have only read sources but I haven't tested it running.

Comment: Unfortunately, `isFormField:false` is not working in 4.2.0 as this property makes fields not editable

Comment: Hmmm, bad luck... Only manually remove the extra fields then. Or (re)consider the upgrade.